# create a client with the wifly shield and an arduino and WiFly.begin() failed

Tags: c, arduino, wifi

I have a problem. I set my wifly shield with TerraTerm, but i can not connect and create a client.

When I use example, my program stop on WiFly.begin() and nothing else...

I would like to create a communication with a server, and send some data to it.
I have a server (with its IP and port), I have a C program wich listen on IP and a specific port.

But now, I want to connect my arduino to this server.

Have you got an issue ?

Thanks you and merry christmas :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If someone had the same problem, here my solution :

I used the WiFlyHQ library, and now it works.